# connect node js with apache ignite thick client

Tags: node.js, ignite

I am trying to connect my nodeJS with Apache ignite regular(thick)client, but i am unable to find any proper documentation or example of that.Can anyone suggest what are the steps for that.

Comment: Why thick client? What exactly are you looking for. Please provide more details

Comment: i am trying to connect my node js app to kubernetes ignite cluster using kuebrnetes ip finder . For that i want to pass xml file for ignite configuration as we do in java. But i don;t find similar method to pass xml file in node js for ignite configuration

Comment: You don't need to use k8s IP finder, it's required for your server nodes only. When the cluster is available, you should be able to connect to it using nodejs thin client (10800 port by default). Therefore you don't need to set any XML configuration from the client app (nodejs)

Comment: In other words, you need to deploy a cluster https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment (it's suitable for local k8s as well) and then establish a connection from a thin client (https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment#connecting-with-thin-clients)

Comment: just one more thing . In kubernetes when we deploy pod every time the address changes. So there is no constant endpoint which we can pass in thin client . So how to use thin client in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as know thick `Ignite` client hasn't been implemented yet. Anyway you should be able to use [thin](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/nodejs-thin-client) `Node.js` client.

Comment: Is there any way so that we can pass our own ignite configuration xml file to thin client.As  in examples available we can only pass the ignite node endpoint.

Comment: Ignite xml configuration is for full scale thick nodes. At the moment thin client doesn't support it.